# Replacing old ceiling fan with new light fixture: light always on?

Tags: wiring, light-fixture, light, rewire

After turning off my breaker, I recently removed an old ceiling fan only to discover a junction box with two white wires and two black wires and a bare copper wired (GND). Upon removing the fan, I noticed that the four halogen lights in the room didn't work anymore...

I installed a brand new light fixture, no fan, (the two whites from the box with the white from the fixture, and the two blacks from the box with the black from the fixture), grounded it and voila, the four halogens now turn on and the light fixture as well... but noticed that the switch only turns off the four halogens and not the light fixture light. In fact, no matter what I do, that light fixture's light always remains remains on.

I checked with my volt meter and found that one of the black wires in the junction box is always hot while the other is regulated by the switch. I looked in the switch box, and to my surprise, I found:

A white and black wire tied together with a wire nut, and another white, black and red attached to the switch itself. So the black and white wire are not attached to the switch itself, but a freely hanging beside it.

I want to be able to at least turn on the four halogens and the light fixture with the switch. Ideally, however, I would like for the light fixture and the ceiling lights to turn on and off independently with a double switch...

To be honest, I've fooled around with this a little too much and I'm planning on hiring an electrician to finish the job, though I would like to get an input on how this could be done regardless. Any input is greatly appreciated!

[image: switch]

The left switch is for the outside porch light. The right one is for the ceiling lights.

Comment: Can you post photos of the inside of the switch box please?

Comment: There's a few things you are leaving off.  First, the switch which operates the halogens is a different switch than the switch that operates the fan.  Second, the halogens only quit working when you split the black and white wires up in there *from each other*.  Third, the fan switch was actually a pull-chain *on the fan*.  And your new light does not have a pull chain. Am I right?

Comment: The fan is gone. I'm installing a chandelier fixture and there is only a single switch on the wall.

Comment: From the sound of it, the box was originally wired for a fan whose switches were on the fan.  I.E. a pull string. Such a fan requires only always-hot and neutral, which accounted for 1 black and 1 white.   However, power also went onward from that location to somewhere else (perhaps the other switch/lamp combo and other places), and that accounts for the other two wires.  It appears no provision was ever made for switching a light there, so this is actually going to be a pretty hard one.

Comment: I take it that switch box only has room for one full-size switch in it?  And yes, can you *please* post photos of its innards?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel I'll be posting photos

Comment: sounds like a perfect time to invest in some smart switches.

Comment: @dandavis -- they don't need a smartswitch to fix this; in fact, a smartswitch would actually be problematic here since they don't make two-circuit versions of those

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel i just mean leave it wired constant on, use wireless switches, and add downstream dimmers; independent control, freedom of switch quantity/placement/meaning, no electrician costs...

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel I posted pictures of the wall switch. The left one turns on the porch light while the other is what controlled the ceiling halogens. Mind you, if I remove the red wire from the switch, no power is provided to the ceiling halogens... if I wire it back, lights come on.

Comment: Can you post a photo of the inside of the box containing the other switch that controls the halogens?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel this is it. This is the only switch that controls the halogens.

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel it’s the only switch. The ceiling box has two white, two black wires.

Comment: Then there's another junction box that had a switch at one point in time....guess you'll have to hunt it down

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel interesting.... I really hope not. I guess you’re right since one of the two black wires in the junction box is always hot regardless of the switch. This would explain why the fixture Is always on. This is okay for a ceiling fan since the fan has its own “switch” by pulling on the chain.... in this since there’s no intermediate switch.   So, my guess is that since one of the two black wires is always hot,  it will supply power to the fixture no matter what, then feed the wall switch, which will then feed the halogens upon flipping switch...

Comment: @Dimitri -- I can tell that the halogens were controlled from two switches at some point as the switch on the right is most definitely a 3-way switch...

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel I found the other switch... it too controls the halogens. It looks the same as the switch above, minus the connected black+white... though this switch doesn’t do  anything for the fixture.

Comment: @Dimitri -- is running new or replacement wiring an option here?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel  If you're talking about opening up walls and all, not really..

Comment: @Dimitri -- it sometimes is possible to "fish" wiring through a wall without having to tear the drywall off wholesale

Comment: Of course. This will be something I need to look into I suppose.